# Transition not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm using jQuery to change icons, and using CSS to apply a transition. For some reason its not working Here's my code

CSS

```
.fa-heart{
  transition: 1s;
}
.fa-heart-o{
  transition: 1s;
}
```

JS

```
$('.fa-heart-o').hover(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');   
}, function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart'); 
});
```

A demo http://jsfiddle.net/cLVBg/1/ Any ideas?

Comment: you forgot to include jquery in your fiddle, i've updated : http://jsfiddle.net/cLVBg/1/

Comment: What kind of transition are you expecting?

Comment: A 1s transition. Like this  http://jsbin.com/jiqufano/1/edit Instead of background color it would be an element @j08691

Comment: But you're not changing any CSS properties. Just the class. In the jsbin the color changes between classes.

Comment: @user302975 but here there is no property to animate, you are just changing pseudo element content

Comment: So would I be able to change the element with a transition at all? @A.Wolff

Comment: That's not the purpose of transition/animation in CSS. You should rethink your logic to animate a background color e.g. BTW, hover pseudo event accept in/out handler, no need in your case to set a mouseleave handler: `$('.fa-heart-o').hover(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart'); 
});`

Answer (score 1):

`content` is not an [animatable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties), thus `transition` does not apply. However if you just want to fill in the heart with a transition in opacity, try working with a [SVG](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aLove_Heart_SVG.svg)- or [CSS-](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#heart)created heart, or just place one on top of another and change their opacity value.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLVBg/5/

Comment: @A.Wolff - I can even do it with `:hover` but I'm lazy to edit so I just copied op's code :P

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is replacing the content on hover. If you want a slow transition, you can use CSS properties to achieve that, like so:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cLVBg/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="transition"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#transition {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#transition:hover {
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The `transition` property requires that you declare another property to apply the transition to. You can select a duration, a transition timing function (`ease`, in this case), and a delay if you want.

Comment: @user302975 I've shown you how to use CSS to create the effect you're looking for. You should be able to apply it yourself to your own code without much difficulty.

Comment: @user3537990 It is the background *of the element*, so it is still transitioning the element.